# How to amend this powershell script to include the password?

Tags: windows, powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0, powershell-4.0

The below code will prompt the user for the password but I want to insert a password in the script (hidden would be preferable). Therefore, the script will run with user inervention and will create and add the user to the admin group.

```
$Password = Read-Host -asSecureString

New-LocalUser -Name User -password $Password  

Add-LocalGroupMember -Group "Administrators" -Member User
```

I modified the script to the below, however I received a secure script error:

```
New-LocalUser -Name User -password Password  

Add-LocalGroupMember -Group "Administrators" -Member User
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText -Force` to convert a string value to a `[SecureString]` instance:

```
$Password = "th3d3f4ultP4$$W0rd!!!" |ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText -Force
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also try something like this (even leaving off the `-UserName User` on the Get-Credential if you want to prompt for both user and password:

```
# will prompt for password, store as secure string
$cred = Get-Credential -UserName User

New-LocalUser -Name $cred.UserName -Password $cred.Password
Add-LocalGroupMember -Group "Administrators" -Member $cred.UserName
```